# How to format or append a string in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c

I want to format the string by this way

```
NSString *title ;
- (void)uploadString:(NSString *)string
{


            title =glbl.text;
            NSMutableString *strRR = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:title];
            [strRR appendFormat:@"%@ .html"];
            [self.googledocs beginUploadData:dataHtml withTitle:title inFolder:self.adirPath replaceExisting:NO];
}
```

`glbl` is the label which holds some values like `genesis1.3` and I want to format this string with `.html` that is `genesis1.3.html. stRR is holding the value`genesis1.3`and I want to append`stRR`with`.html`.  How to do this? I got some error in the above code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error is it you're getting?

Comment: @Kevin program received signal EXC BAD ACCESS HERE i get error [strRR appendFormat:@"%@ .html"];

Comment: You kinda need to learn something about the basic NSString functions before you go much further.  Read through the [NSString spec](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString * stRR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.html", title];
```

Comment: so i put the move code instead of [strRR appendFormat:@"%@ .html"]; this right?

Comment: (Minor detail -- I don't think he really wants the ".stRR" there.  That's the period ending the sentence and the variable name starting the next sentence.)

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo it works fine,sir one more doubt,how to put a static string like ELToch_Bible in front of title.html that is gneiss1.3.html like this ELToch_Bible genesis1.3.html.thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're having a problem because you're not providing anything to satisfy the format in `[strRR appendFormat:@"%@ .html"];`

(And it should be `stringByAppendingFormat:`.)