# how to append string in iphone?

Tags: objective-c

i want to append a date with a string that is m_textdate.text = date has my current date and i want to append this with `NSString * strRR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BibleApp_Notes_%@.html", title];`i get BibleApp_Notes_genisis1.3.html from the above code .title is the string containing genisis1.3,hand i want like this BibleApp_Notes_genisis1.3 [20/05/1986 08:07:08 ].html,but m_textdate.text has the same date formate with me,i just want to appent this date with my move code.
Thnks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format or append a string in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483495/how-to-format-or-append-a-string-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NSString * strRR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BibleApp_Notes_%@ [%@].html", title, m_textdate.text];
```